# Things to Consider While Transferring IonicFramework Project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been developing and Android Application on Windows.

I want to transfer the project from the current computer which is running on Windows to another Windows machine. So, what are the requirements to ensure that the project works fine on the new machine.

**P/S:** The plugins must be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must ensure that all the ENVIROMENT has been set such as : ***SDK, JDK, Ionic/Cordova CLI, npm, bower, etc..***
2. Try to copy all of the project file into new machine then build/run it.

   - In case you can't build/run it:

     - Copy only the `www` folder to the new machine first.
     - Create a new project on the new machine: `ionic start yourAppName blank`
     - Remove the `\yourAppName\www` folder on the new project.
     - Paste the `www` from the old project.
     - Go back to the old machine, open up IONIC CLI (cmd) at the project folder and hit this command to list all the plugin of your project: `ionic plugin ls`.
     - In the new project, add every plugin manually by your hand.
     - Then build and run it.